# RichTextBox set color of user in "user: message"

Tags: vb.net

I'm outputting a number of strings in a richtextbox like this

```
Dim name As String = GetBetween(buf, "@", ".tmi")
Dim message As String = ": " & buf.ToString().Split(":")(2) & Environment.NewLine
RichTextBox1.AppendText(name & message)
```

I want to color the name output of every line in the textbox, this is what i have tried so far:

```
RichTextBox2.AppendText(name)
RichTextBox2.Select(0, name.Length)
RichTextBox2.SelectionColor = Color.Red
RichTextBox2.AppendText(message)
RichTextBox2.Select(name.Length, message.Length)
RichTextBox2.SelectionColor = Color.Black
```

This colors USER red and MESSAGE black, but just for the first line. I've tried doing a for each loop but failed since I don't know how I should do it.

Output: ElementalTree: Hello (ElementalTree is red when the : message is black, but just for the top line)

I'd love some help :)

Edit:
Got it to work just by doing

```
RichTextBox2.SelectionColor = Color.Red
RichTextBox2.AppendText(user)
RichTextBox2.SelectionColor = Color.Black
RichTextBox2.AppendText(message)
```

Thanks Capellan for the suggestion of not using Select!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your SelectionColor before appending, and then don't worry about using Select.  This works for me:

```
    Dim lst As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    lst.Add("user1:message1")
    lst.Add("user2:message2")
    lst.Add("user3:message3")

    For i As Int32 = 0 To lst.Count - 1
        Dim strAry() As String = lst(i).Split({":"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        If Me.RichTextBox1.Text.Length > 0 Then Me.RichTextBox1.SelectedText = Environment.NewLine
        Me.RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
        Me.RichTextBox1.AppendText(strAry(0))
        Me.RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black
        Me.RichTextBox1.AppendText(": " & strAry(1))
    Next
```

Comment: Nvm, fixed this by not using select like you said :) updated thread